# What is the difference between a number n and (n) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

```
print(type(1))
print(type((1)))
```

gives me

```
<class 'int'>
```

Also

```
print(id(1))
print(id((1)))
```

gives me

```
1555424112
1555424112
```

however `(1)` is recognized as an instance where as `1` is not?
for e.g., on doing a `(1)`. in editor I get a lot of methods such as `bit_length`, `conjugate`, `__add__()` etc. but not in doing `1`.

What is the reason for the distinction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(..)` merely *groups* an expression. For integers, it also has the side-effect that the `.` character for *floating point decimals* can be disambiguated from the `.` attribute access operator.

So

```
1.bit_length()
```

is a syntax error, because `bit_length` is not a valid non-integer portion for a real number. But

```
(1).bit_length()
```

is valid Python syntax, because now the parser won't see the `.` token as part of the number literal.

Alternatively, add a space:

```
1 .bit_length()
```

Answer (score 2):

n and (n) are the same expression.

But watch out for this (n,) that is a tuple of one element.

id() is not the way to compare expressions. It tells you if
you objects are the same object. And Python treats small number
specially so that id() is always the same in any python session.

So you get this behaviour:

The id() is the same as id(1) for is(1+1-1)

```
>>> id(1),id(1+1-1)
(140246128484064, 140246128484064)
```

But for larger numbers the id() changes.

```
>>> id(3000000),id(3000000+1-1)
(140246130143120, 140246129522640)
```

Use == for expression comparison.

Comment: See ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313) as to why integers behave this way.

Answer (score -2):

To print it, you would just do 
Print(n1-n2)